# Count all "if" which are present in comment of a code

Tags: javascript, regex

Count number of **if**'s in comments of following code.

```
function testLogicalAnd(val) {
  if(1){
    console.log('Print something');
    // if if
  }
  /*
    if
  */
  /*
    nothing
  */
  return "No";
}
```

There are 3 **if**s in comment.
Is it possible to use regex to find all such **if**'s?

### What i tried is:

I have to find number of **if**'s between **x** and **y** in any text.And later i will replace x,y with (//,\n) for single line comment or (/*,*/) for multiline comment.

Till now what i have tried is:

- `/x[^xy]*(if)[^xy]*y/g` ==>catches only 1 if
- `/x[^xy(if)]*(if)[^xy(if)]*y/g` ==> catches the x-y range where 1 if exist not more than 1
- `/x[[^xy(if)](if)[^xy(if)]]*y/g`==> No match.

I tried more permutations of the above.But i was unable to group all such **if**'s
Check it [here](https://www.regex101.com/r/Dm01V2/3)

Sample text:

> abcdifnoifd**x*if*l*if*lly**fffnoifdded**xdslk*if*y**dadad**xy**
>
> The result is **3**.

Is it possible to achieve such regex? If yes then how should I do grouping?

---

Comment: try this /(\/\/(.*?if.*?)+)|(\/\*((.|\s)*?if(.|\s)*?)+\*\/)/g...it's straightforward and must hopefully work

Comment: I have tried this this just catches the comments which are having if...i have to group all those if's

Comment: I don't think it's possible with a single regex. And even with surrounding code it's nontrivial: You basically have to tokenize JavaScript first (to know whether `/*` and `//` start comments or are part of a string or regex literal), which in turn requires knowing whether the current position expects a value or an operator in the grammar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```js
const regex = /(?=\/\/).*\bif\b|\/\*(?=[\S\s]*\bif\b[\S\s]*)[\S\s]*?\*\//g;
const str = `function testLogicalAnd(val) {
  if(1){//
    console.log('Print something');
    // if if
  }
  /*
    if
  */
  /*
    nothing
  */
  return "No";
}`;
let m;
let count = 0;
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${(match.match(/\bif\b/g) || []).length}`);
        count += (match.match(/\bif\b/g) || []).length;
    });
}
console.log(`The keyword if is present ${count} times`)
```

Comment: i appreciate your effort.but i needed the regex solution only.